# Chrome extension 2 questions

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have managed with my extension and using ajax call in the content script to call my server and get an answer back. But in the console I get a message like:

**The page at https://www.injectedpage.com displayed insecure content from http://www.mywebsite.com/Script.asp**

Is there something I can do to prevent this message appear?

One more question please.
If I distribute the .crx to other people, can they see my code in the .js page? I dont want them to know to which page in my server I post the data I send.

Thank you for reading me. And for your patience with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue is due to the fact that the website you're injecting code into is https while your page is http. It's a security warning from Chrome that you can't hide.

Yes they can see your extension's complete code. You can obfuscate it but when you publish your extension you give the user the entire code.

If your extension has a popup thing from the toolbar, right click to inspect element and If it has a background page or something, you can inspect it from the extensions page (developer mode has to be checked)

To see all of the files of every extensions, a user can navigate to Chrome's extensions directory. For example, on Win7 it's

```
C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions
```

User could also just rename your crx to zip and extract.

Comment: Right now I have the .crx file installed in the browser.
Could you please tell me how can I retrieve the code?

Comment: Oh great...
I guess there is no way to hide such things? Or someone could easily steal someone's else extension and sell it as his one, right?

Comment: Correct. If a program on my computer makes a request to a website, I can find out what it's requesting. That's not just specific to Chrome extensions.